# How to group key bindings in which-key?

Tags: key-bindings, help

I have binded Winum functions to SPC 0 - SPC 9. In which-key minibuffer I see each key by its own (10 labels), which occupies a lot of space. It would be great if I could group all winum keys labels into one label like "0..9". So I wonder there if is some way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this using the variable `which-key-replacement-alist`. This should do what you want. You can manipulate it as needed.

```
(push '(("\\(.*\\) 0" . "winum-select-window-0") . ("\\1 0..9" . "window 0..9"))
      which-key-replacement-alist)
(push '((nil . "winum-select-window-[1-9]") . t) which-key-replacement-alist)
```

The first line tells which-key to replace the binding to `winum-select-window-0` with a description of the range. The final line tells which-key to ignore the bindings to `winum-select-window-[1-9]`.